# Updating Xamarin Forms produces "invalid android support library configuration" error when building.

Tags: xamarin, nuget, android-appcompat

I updated Xamarin Forms to 3.4.0 on a Xamarin Forms Android project that was working fine. Now I am getting this error when attempting to build. The error is "invalid android support library configuration" and when I look at my Package Console I see this...

[image]

...saying that some of my Xamarin.Android.Support.xxx packages need a downgraded package for compatibility. Problems is, my project does not have any of this packages as you can see by my "Packages" folder here...

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. [Images of code are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste the code into your question.

Comment: None of the image are code. It is non copiable text from console output and files.

Comment: The first image is plaintext console output. You can copy the output from your console and paste it into your question. The second image is a directory listing. You can copy the output from `ls | tr '\n' '\n'` and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can happen if you update ALL of the nuget packages in a Xamarin.Forms Android project.

Xamarin.Forms has specific dependencies on specific versions of the Xamarin.Android.Support libraries, and if you update ALL of the nuget packages in the Android project, then the support libraries may update to versions later than the versions that the new Xamarin.Forms version supports.

At this point I would uninstall Xamarin.Forms package from the Android project and also uninstall all of the dependent support library packages, which are listed here under "Dependencies": https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/

So in the Android project, uninstall the following nugets:

```
Xamarin.Forms
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter
```

Once uninstalled, just re-install Xamarin.Forms and the correct versions of the support packages should be re-installed.

In the future, just update the Xamarin.Forms packages and that will automatically update the support library packages if necessary, and will not update the support libraries if the newer support library versions are not supported by the updated Xamarin.Forms version.

Comment: If its specific version dependent shouldn't it say `=` rather than `>=`

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. However there is no way to know in advance if a new version of the support libraries will break Xamarin.Forms for Android or not. The point is that it is best to let Xamarin.Forms update its dependencies when you update Xamarin.Forms package, rather than manually updating the dependencies.

Comment: I have this issue with a Xamarin.Android (non XF) project.

Comment: In 2020, Manually referencing the correct Xamarin.Android.Support versions in your .csproj actually worked for me after 3 hours. Following this tutorial (https://redth.codes/how-to-fix-the-dreaded-version-conflict-nuget-error-in-your-xamarin-android-projects/)

Answer (score 0):

Updating `Xamarin.Forms` and all *.Support.* libraries to the latest version worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a version compatibility problem, if you have updated some packages recently, you must go to the package manager "NuGet/Update" you will find all Xamarin packages need update.